ApexCharts set global default colors with Vue3
How to set global default colors and/or theme palette for ApexCharts using Vue3 + Typescript ?
PS: I'm using quasar cli.
I've tried to set Apex.colors following documentation, but it's not working.

I've tried to set Apex.colors following documentation, but it's not working.


That's quite unfortunate. Meanwhile we will need a [repro] to help you further.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
